# Is there any alternative to synchronize class or method without using 'synchronized' keyword in java?

Tags: synchronization

Is there any alternative to synchronize class or method without using 'synchronized' keyword in java ?

Thanks,
Mallikarjun Kokatanur

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at the changes introduced with the concurrency package, to JDK 5.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/concurrency/

Here are some of what is in the article:

- Semaphore: A classic concurrency tool
- CyclicBarrier: A resettable multiway
  synchronization point (useful for
  parallel programming)
- CountDownLatch: A utility for
  blocking until a given number of
  signals, events, or conditions hold
- Exchanger: Allows two threads to
  exchange objects at a rendezvous
  point, and can be useful in pipeline
  designs

**UPDATE**
The above link is dead but this tutorial is nice, http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/

Basically, examples of using locks and semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "lockable" resource, such as a file.

You can also look at java.util.concurrent.locks which has more sophisticated locking.

Why don't you want to use synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

check out `Lock` classes from `java.util.concurrent.locks` package, which can be more flexible than synchronized methods.